# Azure FHIR: Error when creating a Media Resource

Tags: azure, resources, hl7-fhir

I want to create a Media resource in my Azure FHIR, I follow the standard definition on https://www.hl7.org/fhir/media.html (In summary, there are only 2 mandatory fields: status and Content) but It did not work!.

I try the simplest possible example:
{
  "resourceType": "Media",
  "id": "",
  "status": "unknown",
  "content": {
    "id": "a1",
    "contentType": "audio/mpeg",
    "data": ""
  }
}

But Server shows an error: "Type checking the data: Encountered unknown element 'status' at location 'Resource.status[0]' while parsing"

When remove the status field, the server shows a different error: "Element with min. cardinality 1 cannot be null".

Can anybody tell me what is the correct syntax for creating a Media Resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just attempted to reproduce that but I cannot. When I do a

```
POST https://<myservice>.azurehealthcareapis.com/Media
```

With a payload of:

```
{ "resourceType": "Media", "id": "", "status": "unknown", "content": { "id": "a1", "contentType": "audio/mpeg", "data": "" } }
```

I get `201 CREATED` and return payload of:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Media",
    "id": "7140a11a-dc59-4766-83f9-027a56d69551",
    "meta": {
        "versionId": "1",
        "lastUpdated": "2019-12-26T07:10:46.993+00:00"
    },
    "status": "unknown",
    "content": {
        "id": "a1",
        "contentType": "audio/mpeg"
    }
}
```

Could it be that your instance of the Azure API for FHIR is STU3, but you are using an R4 Media resource. I believe the "status" element was added in R4.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael! I mixed up STU3 and R4.

Followed correct version of Media: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/STU3/media.html, and it was solved!

{
    "resourceType": "Media",
    "id": "d5af5eb3-1402-4249-987e-8ff1c09384b1",
    "meta": {
        "versionId": "1",
        "lastUpdated": "2019-12-27T03:41:16.288+00:00"
    },
    "type": "photo",
    "content": {
        "id": "a1",
        "contentType": "audio/mpeg"
    }
}